# How to get window inner height in office.js dialog

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm using [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). To determine dialog's height I need to get the size of visible area of the screen (i.e. *window.innerHeight*). I tried accessing innerHeight property from within function file or dialog file, but got 0 in both cases. I'm guessing that it's due to dialog running in an *iframe*, but is it possible to get visible screen's area in some other way?

UPDATE: the requirement that I have is to prevent vertical scrollbar in the dialog. I am creating controls dynamically and adding them to the dialog. Thus I need to resize the dialog to fit the controls preventing the vertical scrollbar and extra whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried `screen.availHeight`?

Comment: The height and width to be provided to this API is in percentage so you should not need to calculate on your own. Is their a different scenario for which you need to know the height?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, yes I have tried `screen.availHeight`. It still returns wrong result, e.g. return 1040 instead of 990 for 1080 resolution.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, the requirement that I have is to not prevent vertical scrollbar in the dialog and not to show any extra white space at the bottom of the dialog. My idea was to calculate `height` parameter to match exactly the height of the dialog page. I also realized that screen percentage needed for the dialog differs depending on the screen resolution as available screen height also differs.

Comment: I don't have any good options right now, so all ideas are very welcome. I cannot believe that hard-coding dialog size is the only way to go.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you need. Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593715/set-constant-size-of-dialog-box-using-dialog-api-for-office-online to see if it gives you an idea?

Comment: Thanks, I tried using office-js-helpers, but it didn't help. If only I could set set fixed dialog size in pixels, but it seems not possible with the current dialog API.

Comment: If the helpers don't help, I recommend that you go to Office Developer Voice and vote up this suggestion: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17196659-improve-custom-dialog

Comment: @grg I know it's probably a long shot, but were you able to find a way around this ?