# Set constant size of dialog box using Dialog API for Office Online

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to set a constant size for the dialog box that is opened using the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), by using the min-width/max-width CSS properties or otherwise? The API only allows setting the width and height percentage, which makes the box look inconsistent when resizing or using different resolutions (30% of 1024px is a skinny window, but looks fine for 1920 for example).

I noticed that the "Office Add-ins" store pop up seems to have a min-width/max-width, so that when resizing it maintains a consistent look, and I'm hoping that I can leverage what it does as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
var dim = pixelToPercentage(700, 350);
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/pop-ups/create_export_link.html",
                { height: dim.height, width: dim.width },
                createExportLinkCallback);
```

and the supporting function is:

```
function pixelToPercentage(heightInPixel, widthInPixel) {
    var height = Math.floor(100 * heightInPixel / screen.height);
    var width = Math.floor(100 * widthInPixel / screen.width);
    return { height: height, width: width };
}
```

this way you calculate the dimensions in the percentage format dynamically.

Comment: This works well on the desktop and not at all on-line. It appears that the desktop actually uses a percentage of the screen, but on-line uses a percentage of the browser window. So the same code does not work in both. Very noticeable on a wide monitor (1440x3440).

Answer (score 0):

The [office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) library has a wrapper for the Dialog API that let's you set dimensions in pixels. Might be worth trying it.

EDIT: 
If the helpers don't help, I recommend that you go to [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and vote up this suggestion:[Improve Custom Dialog](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17196659-improve-custom-dialog)

Or create your own.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but internally it looks like the office-js-helpers converts the pixel dimensions to a percentage when calling the dialog API, and so we run into the same problems with resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Alaa's answer, this worked better for me (inside the pixelToPercentage function) to support both web and desktop:

```
var cheight = window.height? window.height : screen.height;
var cwidth = window.height? window.width : screen.width;
if (heightInPixel > cheight) heightInPixel = cheight;
if (widthInPixel > cwidth) widthInPixel = cwidth;
var height = Math.floor(100 * heightInPixel / cheight);
var width = Math.floor(100 * widthInPixel / cwidth);
```